# Join - Syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
public function getIncomeBranches()
{   
    return
    $this->db->select('t1.subject_name, t2.payment_grand, t2,.payment_date, t3.level_id')
                     ->join('groups AS t3', 't1.subject_id = t3.group_id', 'left')
                     ->join('payments AS t2', 't1.subject_id = t2.payment_id')
                     ->group_by('t1.subject_id')
                     ->get("subjects AS t1")->result();
}
```

### Problem

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' `t3`.`level_id` FROM `subjects` AS `t1` LEFT JOIN `groups` AS
>   `t3` ON `t1`.`sub' at line 1

```
SELECT `t1`.`subject_name`, `t2`.`payment_grand`, `t2`, .`payment_date`, `t3`.`level_id` FROM `subjects` AS `t1` LEFT JOIN `groups` AS `t3` ON `t1`.`subject_id` = `t3`.`group_id` JOIN `payments` AS `t2` ON `t1`.`subject_id` = `t2`.`payment_id` GROUP BY `t1`.`subject_id`
```

> Filename:
>   D:/www/domains/uzdev/taraqqiyot/application/models/Dashboard_model.php
>
> Line Number: 69

I want to take subject by id and show all payments to that subject.

Comment: Delete the comma in t2,.payment_date -> t2.payment_date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unwanted `,` in your query `t2,.payment_date,` just remove it from first line

It would be

```
$this->db->select('t1.subject_name, t2.payment_grand, t2.payment_date, t3.level_id')
->join('groups AS t3', 't1.subject_id = t3.group_id', 'left')
                     ->join('payments AS t2', 't1.subject_id = t2.payment_id')
                     ->group_by('t1.subject_id')
                     ->get("subjects AS t1")->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake --> `t2,.payment_date,`

```
public function getIncomeBranches()
{   
    return
    $this->db->select('t1.subject_name, t2.payment_grand, t2.payment_date, t3.level_id')
                     ->join('groups AS t3', 't1.subject_id = t3.group_id', 'left')
                     ->join('payments AS t2', 't1.subject_id = t2.payment_id')
                     ->group_by('t1.subject_id')
                     ->get("subjects AS t1")->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`t2,.payment_date` to `t2.payment_date` and also,

```
$this->db->select('t1.subject_name, t2.payment_grand, t2.payment_date, t3.level_id')
    ->join('groups AS t3', 't1.subject_id = t3.group_id', 'left')
    ->join('payments AS t2', 't1.subject_id = t2.payment_id')
    ->group_by('t1.subject_id')
    ->get("subjects AS t1")->result();
```

While joining, syntax will be this,

```
 $this->db->join("table1","table1.id = table2.id");
```

Just check with second join if its correct.